# How to manually validate a SAMLResponse signature?

Tags: xml, saml

Given the following SAML response, how can I manually validate that the signature is valid? I assume I should rely on the IDP's certificate supplied in metadata and not the one in the response itself (although they should be the same).

Is there some way to do this with openssl or xmlsec1 commands?

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="s2a79da8e2cd2eda272fd5d2d474858f1919430a96" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2016-08-25T00:24:45Z" Destination="http://10.88.111.163:8080/zport/dmd">
  <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://idp.ssocircle.com</saml:Issuer>
  <samlp:Status xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<samlp:StatusCode xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success">
</samlp:StatusCode>
</samlp:Status>
  <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="s22b55a88e8022a4d198715d5b3f21c3fbd699dac4" IssueInstant="2016-08-25T00:24:45Z" Version="2.0">
<saml:Issuer>https://idp.ssocircle.com</saml:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#s22b55a88e8022a4d198715d5b3f21c3fbd699dac4">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>abEMP7cxDW8LwnvcUzr2dHmQesk=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
#SIGNATURE#
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
#CERTIFICATE#
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature><saml:Subject>
<saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" NameQualifier="https://idp.ssocircle.com" SPNameQualifier="instance">ben</saml:NameID><saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
<saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2016-08-25T00:34:45Z" Recipient="http://10.88.111.163:8080/zport/dmd"/></saml:SubjectConfirmation>
</saml:Subject><saml:Conditions NotBefore="2016-08-25T00:14:45Z" NotOnOrAfter="2016-08-25T00:34:45Z">
<saml:AudienceRestriction>
<saml:Audience>instance</saml:Audience>
</saml:AudienceRestriction>
</saml:Conditions>
<saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2016-08-25T00:16:14Z" SessionIndex="s2e2b6d389c12dd386a118286d1228e159faee1901"><saml:AuthnContext><saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></saml:AuthnContext></saml:AuthnStatement><saml:AttributeStatement><saml:Attribute Name="EmailAddress"><saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">me@email.com</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute><saml:Attribute Name="FirstName"><saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Ben</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute></saml:AttributeStatement></saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Comment: The listing you've provided will never validate, as you've improperly decoded the response. The canonicalization is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the verification certificate is in a file called `cert.pem` and the (unmodified, verbatim) SAML response is in `response.xml`, `xmlsec1` can be used to verify the signature on the response as follows:

```
xmlsec1 verify --id-attr:ID "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol:Response" --pubkey-cert-pem cert.pem response.xml
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting an error:
libxml2 library function failed:expr=xpointer(id('s2f27544a6d89dd3d9dae51892cb91e5473966a9c4'))

Comment: you need to look in to the full "stacktrace"

Comment: I needed to use "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion:Assertion" for the ID node. "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol:Response" identified the wrong ID.

Comment: In SAML the response and/or the assertion may be signed; in this case your question should have been "How to manually validate a SAML Assertion signature".

Answer (score 2):

You can use this online tool to verify signature: https://www.samltool.com/validate_response.php

I don't know if openssl or xmlsec1 can validate SAMLResponse's signature, but I know all popular programming languages have libraries/products for doing that.
Some examples are:

C#: OIOSAML https://digitaliser.dk/group/42063/resources

PHP: Simplesamlphp

Java: opensaml or whatever you can find using google.

Comment: Anyone knows such library for Node.js?